# passing string from firebase realtime database request

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

How can I pass the string userImage which I get from a firebase realtime database request? I can not just use return userImage. It says Unexpected non-void return value in void function. I want the userImage as result and paste it to XXXXXX.

```
...
   func datenBankAbfrage() {
        print("datenbankabfrage getriggert")
        dic = [:]
        for name in myFeed.myArray1[0..<myFeed.myArray1.count] {
            ref = Database.database().reference().child("placeID/\(name)")
            
            ref.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
                self.dic[name] = []
                
                var specificNameVideos = [importComment]()
                
                for video in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    let Object1 = video.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                     let timestampDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(Object1?["userTime"] as! NSNumber)/1000)
                    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.YY hh:mm"
                    let time = dateFormatter.string(from: timestampDate as Date)
                    print(time + "Uhr")
                    
                    let userName = Object1?["userName"]
                    ...
                    let kommentarCount = Object1?["kommentarCount"]
                    let userID = Object1?["userID"]
                    
                    //print(userID!)
                    
                    
                    ViewComments.commentIDNew = commentId as! String
                    
                    
                    func wertBerechnen(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
                        self.ref = Database.database().reference()
                        self.ref.child("user/\(userID!)").observeSingleEvent (of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                            let userImage = value?["picture"] as? String ?? ""
                            completion(userImage)
                        })
                    }

                    wertBerechnen { userImage in
                        let video = importComment(
                            userName: userName as! String, userGroup: userGroup as! String,
                            userComment: userComment as! String, userTime: userTime as! String,
                            userLikes: userLikes as! Int, commentId: commentId as! String, placeID: placeID as! String, kommentarCount: kommentarCount as? Int, userImage: userImage)
                        specificNameVideos.append(video)
                    }
                    
                }
                self.dic[name] = specificNameVideos
                let tem = Array(self.dic.values).flatMap { $0 } // You can also sort allComments with userTime property
                self.table = tem.sorted { $0.userTime! > $1.userTime! }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            myFeed.myArray1 = []
        }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a completion handler to return the userImage string:

```
func wertBerechnen(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    self.ref = Database.database().reference()
    self.ref.child("user/\(userID!)").observeSingleEvent (of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let userImage = value?["picture"] as? String ?? ""
        completion(userImage)
    })
}

Then you can call it like this:

wertBerechnen { userImage in
    let video = importComment(
        userName: userName as! String, userGroup: userGroup as! String,
        userComment: userComment as! String, userTime: userTime as! String,
        userLikes: userLikes as! Int, commentId: commentId as! String, placeID: placeID as! String, kommentarCount: kommentarCount as? Int, userImage: userImage)
    specificNameVideos.append(video)
}

self.dic[name] = specificNameVideos
let tem = Array(self.dic.values).flatMap { $0 }
self.table = tem.sorted { $0.userTime! > $1.userTime! }
self.tableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

You need to reload the tableView data inside the wertBerechnen completion handler:

```
func wertBerechnen(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    self.ref = Database.database().reference()
    self.ref.child("user/\(userID!)").observeSingleEvent (of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let userImage = value?["picture"] as? String ?? ""
        completion(userImage)
    })
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
wertBerechnen { userImage in
    let video = importComment(
        userName: userName as! String, userGroup: userGroup as! String,
        userComment: userComment as! String, userTime: userTime as! String,
        userLikes: userLikes as! Int, commentId: commentId as! String, placeID: placeID as! String, kommentarCount: kommentarCount as? Int, userImage: userImage)
    specificNameVideos.append(video)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

self.dic[name] = specificNameVideos
let tem = Array(self.dic.values).flatMap { $0 }
self.table = tem.sorted { $0.userTime! > $1.userTime! }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the code. I tried it but my tableView stays blank. Any idea why? I added a little bit more code above.

Comment: solution amended

Comment: Thanks tried the updated code but still blank. The log shows that the data is loaded but the tableView will not show it.

Comment: Can you help me with this? I can't make it work.